# How can I add an additional user search filter to the LDAP plugin in Plone?

Tags: plone, zope

When I try to add an additional user search filter in the ZMI under /test/acl_users/ldap-plugin/acl_users I get the following error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module Products.LDAPUserFolder.LDAPUserFolder, line 464, in manage_edit
  Module Products.LDAPUserFolder.LDAPDelegate, line 265, in connect
INVALID_CREDENTIALS: {'info': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1', 'desc': 'Invalid credentials'}
```

I am logged in as the admin user created during the install of Plone.

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  have to write again the password every time you save that form, even if the password field seems to be filled.